# How to modify the file name during download on pdf.js mobile devices

Tags: pdf.js

How to modify the file name during download on pdf.js mobile devices,but The mobile application app is not effective and only works in the browser

```
function getPDFFileNameFromURL(url) {
    // Added parameter for obtaining file name on address
    let windowUrl = decodeURIComponent(window.location.href)
    let filename = new URL(windowUrl).searchParams.get('fileName') || ''
    if (filename) return filename

    var defaultFilename = arguments.length > 1 && arguments[1] !== undefined ? arguments[1] : 'document.pdf';

    if (isDataSchema(url)) {
        console.warn('getPDFFileNameFromURL: ' + 'ignoring "data:" URL for performance reasons.');
        return defaultFilename;
    }
    var reURI = /^(?:(?:[^:]+:)?\/\/[^\/]+)?([^?#]*)(\?[^#]*)?(#.*)?$/;
    var reFilename = /[^\/?#=]+\.pdf\b(?!.*\.pdf\b)/i;
    var splitURI = reURI.exec(url);
    var suggestedFilename = reFilename.exec(splitURI[1]) || reFilename.exec(splitURI[2]) || reFilename.exec(splitURI[3]);
    if (suggestedFilename) {
        suggestedFilename = suggestedFilename[0];
        if (suggestedFilename.indexOf('%') !== -1) {
            try {
                suggestedFilename = reFilename.exec(decodeURIComponent(suggestedFilename))[0];
            } catch (ex) { }
        }
    }
    return suggestedFilename || defaultFilename;
}
```